# Angularjs show validation if one or more value is empty in the array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, validation, is-empty

I have an angularjs [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/o26v8eox/1/) where I used `ng-repeat` as

```
<div ng-app="Test">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <div ng-repeat="str in myData">{{str.id}}. {{str.string}}</div>
        <br/> <span ng-if="myData.length > 1" style="color:red;">One or more string is empty</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

to draw the list from an array. I want to show an validation if there are one or more value pf string in the array is empty. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the array in your controller and increment a variable say `count` when your string is empty. Based on that `count` value you can manage your UI elements.

For Example:
In you controller:

```
    $scope.count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myData.length; i++){
        if($scope.myData[i].string === ""){
            $scope.count ++;
        }
    }
```

In you HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="str in myData">{{str.id}}. {{str.string}}</div>
    <br/> 
    <span ng-if="count >= 1" style="color:red;">One or more string is empty</span>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just initialize $scope.count=0 now you can perform your task.....

```
 <div ng-app="Test"> 
 <div ng-controller="TestController">
 <div ng-repeat="str in myData">{{str.id}}. {{str.string}} 
 <span ng-if="str.length < 1" ng-int="count=+1">
 </div>
 <br/> 
 <span ng-if="count > 1" style="color:red;">One or more string is empty</span>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: I wanted the single validation for all values. Please see the accepted answer above.