# angularjs validation is not hiding on typing in the text field

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-click

With extending the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857161/angularjs-show-validation-if-one-or-more-value-is-empty-in-the-array/33858111#33858111), Myself trying to hide the validation message on typing in the text field as,

```
 $scope.click = function () {
        showVal();
    }

    function showVal() {
        $scope.count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myData.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.myData[i].string === "") {
                $scope.count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

and my text field is,

```
 <div ng-repeat="str in myData">
            <input type="text" ng-model="str.string" ng-click="click()">
        </div>
        <br/> <span ng-if="count >= 1" style="color:red;">One or more string is empty</span>
```

as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/8z1uc011/). Why the validation is not hiding eventhough the condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ngChnage` instead of `ngClick` http://jsfiddle.net/8z1uc011/1/

Comment: What a silly mistake :( Thank you for correcting me :)